# Getting issue while using gmail as smtp

Tags: asp.net, smtp, gmail

**Code**

[image]

**Issue**
and getting this error
[image]

Comment: Please don't paste your code as a picture, copy in the actual code.

Comment: Have you tried to read what Google says about your mail? It is linked at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69585

Comment: @Emil  In this editor Very difficult to format the code so i added image here.

Comment: @Steve yes, But didn’t get much

Comment: I think they considered your mail as spam and refused to deliver. (If you paste the code I will reformat for you)